# Как поместить exe файл в программу?

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно засунуть 2.exe в 1.exe и при нажатии на кнопку (button1) в программе (1.exe), 2.exe должен запустится.(Необходимо чтобы пользователь не мог запустить 2.exe не запуская 1.exe) Надеюсь я понятно объяснил)) Заранее очень благодарен.

Comment: дроппер? помещаем в ресурсы и расспаковываем когда нужно.

Comment: Нет, не дроппер.А можно каким-нибудь другим способом?

Comment: Конечно, можно. Обрабатываем файл с помощью base64 и сохраняем в файле в виде строки. Когда нужно - делаем распаковку в файл и запускаем:) Но это не рекомендовано к исполнению:)

Comment: Почему не рекомендовано? 
P.S. Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь не смог скопировать 2.exe при распаковке(И запускать потом его отдельно).

Comment: Я так понял, нужно использование, максимально близкое к библиотеке. Типа в памяти распаковать и запустить) @Haulm, исходников 2.exe естественно нет?

Comment: Да, направление правильное) Исходников нет, но это не важно(1.ехе и 2.ехе могут быть любые файлы)

Answer (score 2):

Через ресурсы RC_DATA, вкладываются компилятором/линкером (зависит от платформы),
извлекается с помощью Win32 API (названия забыл), вытаскиваешь 2.exe из ресурса 1.exe в файловую систему и запускаешь.

Если из под Delphi, то вроде есть работа с ресурсами в TStream, или вроде есть TResourceStream или что-то вроде этого.

В Delphi ресурс вставляется просто:

{$R 1.exe}